# Python function that automatically extracts conformed-to-schema data from a json

Tags: python, json, api

I have some Python script/job that daily calls an API, transforms the data and stores it to a data store. The problem is the API has been changing the schema of the JSON (adding some fields mainly), so the job fails. I can of course, just write in the script to parse the fields needed for the data store, but I just wonder if there is some Python utility/function/library which reads some JSON schema definition (written in a file to be read by the script) and simply extract the data from the JSON based on what conforms to that schema definition.